# How do I completely uninstall version 2.19 of the module?

Tags: commerce

I'm supporting a Drupal installation (8.9.0) with commerce 2.19 installed. The customer wants commerce to become uninstalled. I've managed to get rid of the majority of commerce configuration.

What stays are: order type recurring and order item type recurring. There is no way to delete those, as the delete option is hidden.

The uninstall site shows:

> Commerce Recurring
>     Provides recurring billing for Drupal
> Commerce
>  The module "Commerce Recurring" can't be uninstalled
> because:
> The field type "Billing period" is used in fields: commerce_order.billing_period, commerce_order_item.billing_period

There is no way to delete either field. If I try to delete the fields via drush `cdel` it leads to other errors and doesn't help. How to continue with uninstall task? As long as this module can't be uninstalled the rest of the commerce will remain.

Comment: As the [module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring) mentions, this module cannot be uninstalled due to this core bug, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2871486. Apply the 8.9.x patch and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've implemented the patch. However I still can't access any of the fields nor uninstall the module because of the field constrains. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try Comment #10 in https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/2924965

Comment: Thanks again. The hint from #10 wasnt't completely correct. I had to comment out the line regarding 'commerce_order.recurring.order_items' because that gave an error. After that I was able to uninstall the commerce recurring module and one by one all of the other modules.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a known bug resolved in https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/2924965.